# rails module/namspace import

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my rails code

```
@swimming_classschedule = Swimming::Classschedule.find(params[:id])
```

It works but it looks tedious everytime i have use this module name `Swimming::`

Is there a way like python

I can `import Classschedule from Swimming` So I can save typing the module name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are objects just like any other. You can assign them to variables just like any other:

```
CS = Swimming::Classschedule

@swimming_classschedule = CS.find(params[:id])
```

If you want to mix in *all* constants (and methods!) defined in a module, you can use `Module#include`:

```
include Swimming

@swimming_classschedule = Classschedule.find(params[:id])
```